# What is the best way to build an apk file in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have been writing an app in flutter recently,
But I faced with some problems I need to know how to solve them:

1-My app consists of 10 lines of code.
Why is it known as a fat file (10.3 MB) , when i Run;

> flutter build apk

after that
the android studio says you can use two ways to build apk:

A)

> flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64

B)

> flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64 --split-per-abi

whem i run `flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64`
 it decreases the code size to 10.4 Mb

when i run  `flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64 --split-per-abi`

it splits the apk file and makes two files (each 5 MB)

What is the difference between the outputs A and B?

In the second modes, what is the reason of the splitting in "APK" files?

What is your best offer for the different types of outputs????

I need an output with reasonable size for aspecific device, what is the solution?
.
tnx.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use app bundle, play store will be delivering the correct version to users.
2. split-per-abi will split per instruction set, you actually defined it on the command line, one for 32 bit, one for 64 bit. (but simply use app bundle which contains both, and play store will split it for you)
3. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16833#issuecomment-447151309 - ~5MB for an empty App is expected.